# How to dynamically generate carousel simultaneously changing and adjusting responsively using Wordpress Sage and Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, tailwind-css, carousel

## Hello!

Perhaps someone will be able to help me.
I built a website based on Wordpress Sage and Tailwind CSS.
There is a carousel module in the project, which looks like that:
[Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3J1E.png)
The problem is that the last photo in the carousel block takes up two rows. I am not able to dynamically generate such content in the carousel, which would simultaneously change (scrolling right/left) and adjust responsively to the width of the screen (another attachment).
Have any of you encountered a similar challenge on Sage?
I found a component that perfectly reflects the effect I want to achieve: https://splidejs.com/extensions/grid
The problem is that the documentation is basically zero and I am unable to recreate the example in the link.
If anyone has an idea how to solve this, I would be grateful for a hint or direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use [splide](https://splidejs.com/) with the splide [grid extension](https://splidejs.com/extensions/grid/#overview), you can try something like this:

**Install the splide and splide grid extension via npm:**

`npm install @splidejs/splide`

`npm install @splidejs/splide-extension-grid`

**Create your HTML markup for the slides:**

```
<section class="splide" id="example" aria-label="Splide Basic GRID Example">
      <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list">
                <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
                <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
                <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
                <li class="splide__slide">Slide 04</li>
                <li class="splide__slide">Slide 05</li>
                <li class="splide__slide">Slide 06</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</section>
```

**Import splide and splide grid extension, configure your splide instance and mount it, like this:**

```
 <script>
        import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';
        import { Grid } from '@splidejs/splide-extension-grid';

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            new Splide('#example', {
                arrows: false,
                pagination: true,
                label: 'My GRID example',
                grid: {
                    rows: 2,
                    cols: 1,
                    gap: {
                        row: '12px',
                        col: '12px',
                    },
                },
            }).mount({ Grid });
        });
    </script>
```

Note, you need to use `.mount({ Grid })`. There are other ways to do this too. Additionally, you could consider [Swiper JS](https://swiperjs.com/), which can also be used for [grid-sliders](https://swiperjs.com/demos#grid).